# how it works @BindsInstance dagger 2

Tags: dagger-2, dagger

I have recently updated dagger 2.8 to 2.9 dagger. and documentation of the last release have been added as follows:

-Added `@BindsInstance` for component builders to easily bind instances that are constructed outside of the graph.

-Producers: Added `ProducerMonitor.ready ()`, which is called when all of a producer's inputs are available.

-Removed `@Provides(type =...)` usage. Use the annotations in `dagger.multibindings` instead. `@Produces.type` was also removed.

-All binding methods are now validated, even if they are unused in a particular `@Component`

-`@Component.dependencies` can no longer include `@Modules`.

I want to know how these new features:

Thank you!!

Note: I am new to dagger 2, but you want to be able to make maximum use of this library.

Answer (score 44):

@bindsInstance is used for removing constructor from module and chaining modules where you get component.

Without `@BindsInstance`

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private final Application application;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application provideApplication() {
        return  application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public SharedPreferences providePreferences() {
        return application.getSharedPreferences("store",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

These modules(ToastMakerModule, and SensorControllerModule) are for learning purposes they get context and instantiate , may not be practical for real examples

```
public class ToastMaker {

    private Application application;

    public ToastMaker(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    public void showToast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(application, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

    @Module
    public class ToastMakerModule {

        @Singleton
        @Provides
        ToastMaker provideToastMaker(Application application) {
            return  new ToastMaker(application);

        }
   }

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ToastMakerModule.class, SensorControllerModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

    // DaggerAppComponent.build() returns this Builder interface

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        AppComponent build();

        Builder appModule(AppModule appModule);

        Builder sensorControllerModule(SensorControllerModule sensorControllerModule);

        Builder toastMakerModule(ToastMakerModule toastMakerModule);
    }

}
```

Build component like this

```
 appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .sensorControllerModule(new SensorControllerModule())
                .toastMakerModule(new ToastMakerModule())
                .build();
```

---

With `@BindsInstance`

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    public SharedPreferences providePreferences(Application application) {
        return application.getSharedPreferences("data",
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }
}
```

Component

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, ToastMakerModule.class, SensorControllerModule.class})

public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {

        AppComponent build();


        // @BindsInstance replaces Builder appModule(AppModule appModule)
        // And removes Constructor with Application AppModule(Application)

        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);
    }
}
```

and build component like this

```
   appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .application(this)
                .build();
```

Comment: Do you know where this annotation @UserName is coming from in official doc? https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#binding-instances

Comment: can you mention where does Build component part goes? Newbie here

Comment: @Arun, i meant you build the component using the snippet below by "Build component", and changed it now.

Answer (score 1):

`@BindsInstance` lets the component host the dependency directly and hence the lifetime is the lifetime of the component. This can be used to avoid `@Singleton` scope. Does it even matter? Avoiding singleton scope helps `DaggerAppComponent` access the provider without a costly DoubleCheck. So yes, it is possible to still use the module and not use any scopes. However, using module still means that `DaggerAppComponent` is going to use a Provider factory to inject the dependency. Using `@BindsInstance`, the provider is not needed at all unless the dependency is injected lazily via `Lazy<>` or `Provider<>`.

Any dependencies (like String constants etc) that is known as `AppComponent` is being created are good candidates for `@BindsInstance`. Note this is based on **Dagger 2.19.**